# I'd like to know if I can take a couple of powerbanks and connect them into one power bank

Tags: batteries, powerbanks

I'm kind of new in the electric things and I'm also a teenager so I don't have that much knowledge. I learned about Arduinos and very basic stuff so I would like to do this as kind of a project to understand some more.

I have a lot of powerbanks at home that we don't charge so all are drained all the time. I wanted to take them all and connect them into one so it would be the only one which needs to be charged.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can purchase a charger designed to do just that. They are not that expensive and individually control the charge on each of the cells. The one I purchased does 12 cells. I purchased it from my favorite china supplier for about $25 us. I did it because it is much easier then connecting a lot of individual chargers and the associated mess. You can use your search engine and enter "LI battery charger for 8 batteries", 8 is a number I used to force it to search for more than a two cell cell charger.

Answer (score 0):

There are several failure modes in 5V Battery Banks and once depleted for months are of no use due to chemical damage and high resistance. But some modes may fail with one bad bank pulling down the rest.

But if you know how to estimate current of charging and discharging, you can weed out the useless banks by charging for a minute and then loading for an equal mA-minutes and say get half the discharge capacity, maybe it is worth using.

Then you need to design a ganged connector panel and choose a power source that is adequate and protected from shorts. such as 12W. If only one bank is good you rely on it's smart charging limiting the capacity of a higher power source like 200W from a PC tower. There exist small devices called polyfuses rated like wire fuses but recover when cooled down. Digikey and Mouser etc. carry lots of different ranges and they look like capacitors.

[of course you can buy these too](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/224391851928?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=706-159614-043509-9&mkcid=2&itemid=224391851928&targetid=4586269160971574&device=c&mktype=&googleloc=&poi=&campaignid=414169804&mkgroupid=1322713655057161&rlsatarget=pla-4586269160971574&abcId=9300552&merchantid=136822&msclkid=a40cab9c482c18fe1f4ec99b9e2c0833)

[image]

Comment: No Arduino's needed. Just cables and Polyfuses and a PC PSU 5V. in a larger bank. (think rugged vault). We use a similar concept for USB charging mobiles with a central 65W charger. Which you can buy with 12W per port limited.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a lot of powerbanks at home that we don't charge so all are
> drained all the time. I wanted to **take them all and connect them into**
> **one so it would be the only one which needs to be charged**.

The first thing you need to understand about power banks is that they are not just a battery. A typical power contains a (nominally) 3.7 V [Lithium-ion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery) or [Lithium-polymer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery) cell, a [voltage booster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) to produce 5 V output, and a Lithium battery [charger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_charger) to recharge the cell (usually powered from +5 V USB).

Simply connecting a number of power banks in parallel may not work properly because each voltage booster tries to regulate its own output voltage. When two or more switching regulator outputs are connected together they 'fight' each other, resulting in either the one with slightly higher voltage winning or one or both regulators blowing up.

Some power banks also have a circuit that keeps them turned off until a load is detected. If it does work you will probably find that one power bank takes over until it is completely drained, followed by the next one etc. This is not much better than what you have now.

The other issue is that if you want to recharge this 'combined' power bank you either need multiple power supplies or a single power supply that can deliver the current required to charge all individual power banks at once.

The next option is to take the power banks apart, remove the cells from all but one and wire them in parallel to make a higher capacity battery. Of course this larger battery won't fit inside the power bank you use it with, but electrically it will work fine.

The downsides of combining cells are a much longer recharge time, a difficult and dangerous modification (lithium batteries can and do ['explode'](https://mountaineerins.com/2019/12/01/lithium-battery-explosions-facts-you-need-to-know/) when improperly handled) and likely early failure of the mismatched cells. For these reasons I advise against it.

That leaves you pretty much out of options for making a larger power bank out of two smaller ones. If your units are drained most of the time then their batteries are probably getting tired. The simplest and safest way to fix this is to simply buy a new power bank with the capacity you desire.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry but this question is really too broad and lacking in detail to have a meaningful answer. On the other hand, playing around with lithium batteries can be quite dangerous.

So, to answer your question, yes it can be done. But it requires great care and extra electronics to do safely. You must ensure that the charging and discharging of these cells is balanced, that they don't get too hot, and that the current is safely limited. If you aren't certain of the safety then I recommend that you don't open the powerbanks.

Comment: well sorry for my bad explanation or English
but what I wanted to ask is that I have a couple of power banks and I wanted to know if I can remove their batteries and connect them together so they could power as one big power bank with more mAh, there are some 10000 mAh and some with 20000 so I wanted to know if I can make one big one from all of them

Comment: I understood what you were asking, but we would need a lot more information about the condition of the cells and exactly how you planned to "connect them together". Small differences in connections can have disastrous consequences.

Comment: oh ok my bad, they're condition is pretty new but ur saying its dangerous so I guess I won't do its, not for now because idk nothing yet, thank you very much tho!